# 2S Li-Ion balancing and pack selection

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms

I'm working on a project where I want/have to use a 2S Li-Ion battery-pack. I want my design to be as safe as possible, which is I why I want to use a battery-pack that is protected by an internal BMS.

Most ressources state that balancing is absolutely necessary when using a 2S-configuration. Why is it that I can't find any 2S battery packs with an internal BMS that include a balancing-lead? Most packs have 2, some have 3 leads and include an NTC (which I plan on using anyway). One could guess that the BMS itself does the balancing but this isn't actually stated anywhere. I have checked out some of the protection modules (e.g. [PCB-2S20W LI-2S](https://www.batteryspace.com/prod-specs/3006-PCB-2S20W.pdf)）that are used in the battery-packs advertised on e.g. batteryspace and those include a "COM" connection that connects the mid-point of both cells to the BMS. Does such a mid-point indicate a cell-balancing function or does this serve a different purpose?

My project does not deal with crazy discharge rates (3-4A for short periods max, about 1-1.5 A continuous drain) but actually choosing the right and "safe" battery-pack does not seem to be that trivial.

What is the right way to go about the balancing topic and am I right in assuming that there are indeed BMS-boards that balance the cells on their own?

Comment: "Does such a mid-point indicate a cell-balancing function" - not necessarily, it may be just to shut the whole pack off if the voltage of one cell gets too low even if the other is still ok.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the meantime I have contacted a distributor of cells/battery-packs which informed me that balancing just isn't seen as critical/neccessary for low-discharge packs or those with less than 4 series cells.  
Furthermore the datasheets of the protection ICs used in e.g. the PCB-2S20W PCM indicate that the mid-point is indeed being used to monitor the cell-voltage to shut the pack off, just as you explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As mentioned in the comment above and in reference to what the engineers at batteryspace told me:** Balancing is not seen as a critical feature on **low-discharge** Li-Ion packs or such packs that have **less than 4 cells in series**.

While there is a "COM" or "MID" connection on most protection modules, this may not be a direct indicator of a balancing function and could instead be used to monitor the individual cell-voltages as seen on e.g. the [PCB-2S20W LI-2S](https://www.batteryspace.com/prod-specs/3006-PCB-2S20W.pdf) module.

There are however some protection modules like the [PCM-S2A5B](https://www.batteryspace.com/prod-specs/365.pdf) that do offer a balance function, which is explicitly mentioned in the datasheet.